# Return the sum of odd digits of a number

Tags: racket

For class, I have to write a function that takes positive integer n and returns the sum of n’s odd digits in scheme. So far, I have my base case such that if n equals 0 then 0. But I am not sure on how to continue.

```
(define sumOddDigits
     (lambda (n)
       (if (= n 0)
           0
```

Test cases:

```
(sumOddDigits 0) → 0
(sumOddDigits 4) → 0
(sumOddDigits 3) → 3
(sumOddDigits 1984) → 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it efficiently using one functional loop:

```
(define (sumOddDigits n)
  (let loop ([n n])
    (cond [(zero? n) 0]
          [else
           (let-values ([(q r) (quotient/remainder n 10)])
             (+ (if (odd? r) r 0)
                (loop q)))])))
```

Answer (score 0):

One can get list of digits using following function which uses 'named let':

```
  (define (getDigits n)
    (let loop ((ol '())            ; start with an empty outlist
               (n n))
      (let-values (((q r) (quotient/remainder n 10)))
        (if (= q 0) (cons r ol)
            (loop (cons r ol) q)))))
```

Then one can apply a filter using odd? function to get all odd elements of list- and then apply 'apply' function with '+' to add all those elements:

```
  (apply + (filter
            (lambda(x)
              (odd? x))
            digitList))
```

Together following can be the full function:

```
(define (addOddDigits N)

  (define (getDigits n)
    (let loop ((ol '())
               (n n))
      (let-values (((q r) (quotient/remainder n 10)))
        (if (= q 0) (cons r ol)
            (loop (cons r ol) q)))))

  (define digitList (getDigits N))

  (println digitList)

  (apply + (filter
            (lambda(x)
              (odd? x))
            digitList)))
```

Testing:

```
(addOddDigits 156)
```

Output:

```
'(1 5 6)
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basecase is if n < 10. Because you are then on the last digit. 
You then need to check if it's odd, and if so return it. Else, return the addition qualifier(0).

If n > 10, you remainder off the first digit, then test it for odd.
If odd, then add it to a recursive call, sending in the quotient of 10(shaves off the digit you just added).
Else, you recursively call add-odds with the quotient of 10, without adding the current digit.

Here it is in a recursive form(Scheme LOVES recursion) :

```
(define add-odds
  (lambda (n)
    (if(< n 10)
       (if(= (remainder n 2) 1)
          n
          0)
       (if(= (remainder (remainder n 10) 2) 1)
          (+ (remainder n 10) (add-odds (quotient n 10)))
          (add-odds(quotient n 10))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

First get a (reversed) list of digits with simple recursive implementation:

```lisp
(define (list-digits n)
  (if (zero? n) '()
      (let-values ([(q r) (quotient/remainder n 10)])
        (cons r (list-digits q)))))
```

then filter the odd ones and sum them:

```lisp
(define (sum-of-odd-digits n)
  (apply + (filter odd? (list-digits n))))
```

Note: `(list-digits 0)` returns `'()` but it is ok for later usage.

More accurate `list-digits` iterative implementation (produce list of digits in right order):

```lisp
(define (list-digits n)
  (define (iter n acc) 
    (if (zero? n) acc
        (let-values ([(q r) (quotient/remainder n 10)])
          (iter q (cons r acc)))))
  (iter n '()))
```